# tensorflow: Errors when building op using g++ 6.3.0 (via MinGW) on Windows 7

Tags: tensorflow, g++, mingw

I'm brand-new to tensorflow and am aiming to run a pre-built model created by another user. As an initial step in this process, I'm trying to build several ops. However, I have been unable to build even basic ops, let alone those that actually perform useful tasks. To give an example, I followed [these directions](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/+/r0.7/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.md) and created the following as `zero_out.cc`:

```
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"

REGISTER_OP("ZeroOut")
    .Input("to_zero: int32")
    .Output("zeroed: int32");

using namespace tensorflow;

class ZeroOutOp : public OpKernel {
 public:
  explicit ZeroOutOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {}

  void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
    // Grab the input tensor
    const Tensor& input_tensor = context->input(0);
    auto input = input_tensor.flat<int32>();

    // Create an output tensor
    Tensor* output_tensor = NULL;
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, input_tensor.shape(),
                                                     &output_tensor));
    auto output = output_tensor->template flat<int32>();

    // Set all but the first element of the output tensor to 0.
    const int N = input.size();
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
      output(i) = 0;
    }

    // Preserve the first input value if possible.
    if (N > 0) output(0) = input(0);
  }
};
```

Afterward, I attempted to run the following in `cmd` (calling `g++ 6.3.0`, which I installed via `MinGW`):

```
g++ -std=c++11 -msse2 -shared zero_out.cc -o zero_out.so -I "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include" -l tensorflow_framework -L "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow" -fPIC -Wl,-rpath "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow"
```

The above line did not produce an `.so` file and instead yielded an assortment of errors (which I've truncated to satisfy the Stack Overflow character limit):

```
In file included from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/message_lite.h:48:0,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/generated_enum_util.h:36,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/map.h:48,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/generated_message_table_driven.h:34,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op_def.pb.h:26,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_builder.h:24,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:23,
                 from zero_out.cc:1:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/stubs/once.h:43:24: error: 'once_flag' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
 using once_flag = std::once_flag;
                        ^~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/stubs/once.h: In function 'void google::protobuf::internal::call_once(Args&& ...)':
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/stubs/once.h:46:3: error: 'call_once' is not a member of 'std'
   std::call_once(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
   ^~~
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/stubs/once.h:46:3: note: suggested alternative:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/stubs/once.h:45:6: note:   'google::protobuf::internal::call_once'
 void call_once(Args&&... args ) {
      ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h:62:0,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.h:47,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op_def.pb.h:30,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_builder.h:24,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:23,
                 from zero_out.cc:1:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/stubs/mutex.h: At global scope:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/stubs/mutex.h:107:8: error: 'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
   std::mutex mu_;
        ^~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/stubs/mutex.h: In member function 'void google::protobuf::internal::WrappedMutex::Lock()':
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/stubs/mutex.h:99:43: error: 'mu_' was not declared in this scope
   void Lock() GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_ACQUIRE() { mu_.lock(); }
                                           ^~~
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/stubs/mutex.h: In member function 'void google::protobuf::internal::WrappedMutex::Unlock()':
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/stubs/mutex.h:100:45: error: 'mu_' was not declared in this scope
   void Unlock() GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_RELEASE() { mu_.unlock(); }
                                             ^~~
In file included from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.h:47:0,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op_def.pb.h:30,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_builder.h:24,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:23,
                 from zero_out.cc:1:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h: At global scope:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h:221:13: error: 'once_flag' in namespace 'google::protobuf::internal' does not name a type
   internal::once_flag* once_;
             ^~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h: In member function 'void google::protobuf::internal::LazyDescriptor::Init()':
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h:189:5: error: 'once_' was not declared in this scope
     once_ = nullptr;
     ^~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h: At global scope:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h:787:13: error: 'once_flag' in namespace 'google::protobuf::internal' does not name a type
   internal::once_flag* type_once_;
             ^~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h:1461:13: error: 'once_flag' in namespace 'google::protobuf::internal' does not name a type
   internal::once_flag* dependencies_once_;
             ^~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h: In member function 'google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor::Type google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor::type() const':
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h:2053:7: error: 'type_once_' was not declared in this scope
   if (type_once_) {
       ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op_def.pb.h:30:0,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_builder.h:24,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:23,
                 from zero_out.cc:1:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.h: At global scope:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.h:271:3: error: 'once_flag' does not name a type
   once_flag* once;
   ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:32:0,
                 from zero_out.cc:1:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/platform/mutex.h:231:8: error: 'cv_status' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
   std::cv_status wait_for(mutex_lock& lock,
        ^~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/platform/mutex.h: In function 'tensorflow::ConditionResult tensorflow::WaitForMilliseconds(tensorflow::mutex_lock*, tensorflow::condition_variable*, tensorflow::int64)':
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/platform/mutex.h:249:3: error: 'cv_status' is not a member of 'std'
   std::cv_status s = cv->wait_for(*mu, std::chrono::milliseconds(ms));
   ^~~
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/platform/mutex.h:250:11: error: 's' was not declared in this scope
   return (s == std::cv_status::timeout) ? kCond_Timeout : kCond_MaybeNotified;
           ^
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/platform/mutex.h:250:21: error: 'std::cv_status' has not been declared
   return (s == std::cv_status::timeout) ? kCond_Timeout : kCond_MaybeNotified;
                     ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/platform/mutex.h:310:0,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:32,
                 from zero_out.cc:1:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/platform/default/mutex.h: At global scope:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/platform/default/mutex.h:25:6: error: 'cv_status' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
 std::cv_status wait_until_system_clock(
      ^~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/platform/default/mutex.h:31:6: error: 'cv_status' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
 std::cv_status condition_variable::wait_for(
      ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1:0,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/numeric_types.h:20,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h:26,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h:24,
                 from zero_out.cc:2:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:44:17: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef long int int32_t'
 typedef __int32 int32_t;
                 ^~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\stdint.h:9:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cstdint:41,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:420,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\string:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\stdexcept:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\array:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\tuple:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\functional:55,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:19,
                 from zero_out.cc:1:
c:\mingw\include\stdint.h:62:15: note: previous declaration as 'typedef int int32_t'
 typedef int   int32_t;
               ^~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1:0,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/numeric_types.h:20,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h:26,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h:24,
                 from zero_out.cc:2:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:45:26: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef long unsigned int uint32_t'
 typedef unsigned __int32 uint32_t;
                          ^~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\stdint.h:9:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cstdint:41,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:420,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\string:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\stdexcept:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\array:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\tuple:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\functional:55,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:19,
                 from zero_out.cc:1:
c:\mingw\include\stdint.h:63:19: note: previous declaration as 'typedef unsigned int uint32_t'
 typedef unsigned  uint32_t;
                   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/platform/notification.h:27:0,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/lib/core/notification.h:21,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/cancellation.h:22,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h:25,
                 from zero_out.cc:2:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/platform/default/notification.h: In member function 'bool tensorflow::Notification::WaitForNotificationWithTimeout(tensorflow::int64)':
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/platform/default/notification.h:69:20: error: 'class tensorflow::condition_variable' has no member named 'wait_for'; did you mean 'wait'?
                cv_.wait_for(l, std::chrono::microseconds(timeout_in_us)) !=
                    ^~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/platform/default/notification.h:70:25: error: 'std::cv_status' has not been declared
                    std::cv_status::timeout);
                         ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1:0,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:22,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/device_base.h:26,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h:27,
                 from zero_out.cc:2:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor: At global scope:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:44:17: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef long int int32_t'
 typedef __int32 int32_t;
                 ^~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\stdint.h:9:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cstdint:41,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:420,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\string:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\stdexcept:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\array:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\tuple:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\functional:55,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:19,
                 from zero_out.cc:1:
c:\mingw\include\stdint.h:62:15: note: previous declaration as 'typedef int int32_t'
 typedef int   int32_t;
               ^~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1:0,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:22,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/device_base.h:26,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h:27,
                 from zero_out.cc:2:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:45:26: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef long unsigned int uint32_t'
 typedef unsigned __int32 uint32_t;
                          ^~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\stdint.h:9:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cstdint:41,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:420,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\string:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\stdexcept:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\array:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\tuple:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\functional:55,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:19,
                 from zero_out.cc:1:
c:\mingw\include\stdint.h:63:19: note: previous declaration as 'typedef unsigned int uint32_t'
 typedef unsigned  uint32_t;
                   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1:0,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.h:21,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:24,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/device_base.h:26,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h:27,
                 from zero_out.cc:2:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:44:17: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef long int int32_t'
 typedef __int32 int32_t;
                 ^~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\stdint.h:9:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cstdint:41,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:420,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\string:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\stdexcept:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\array:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\tuple:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\functional:55,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:19,
                 from zero_out.cc:1:
c:\mingw\include\stdint.h:62:15: note: previous declaration as 'typedef int int32_t'
 typedef int   int32_t;
               ^~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1:0,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.h:21,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:24,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/device_base.h:26,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h:27,
                 from zero_out.cc:2:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:45:26: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef long unsigned int uint32_t'
 typedef unsigned __int32 uint32_t;
                          ^~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\stdint.h:9:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cstdint:41,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:420,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\string:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\stdexcept:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\array:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\tuple:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\functional:55,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:19,
                 from zero_out.cc:1:
c:\mingw\include\stdint.h:63:19: note: previous declaration as 'typedef unsigned int uint32_t'
 typedef unsigned  uint32_t;
                   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1:0,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_types.h:19,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:25,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/device_base.h:26,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h:27,
                 from zero_out.cc:2:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:44:17: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef long int int32_t'
 typedef __int32 int32_t;
                 ^~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\stdint.h:9:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cstdint:41,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:420,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\string:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\stdexcept:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\array:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\tuple:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\functional:55,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:19,
                 from zero_out.cc:1:
c:\mingw\include\stdint.h:62:15: note: previous declaration as 'typedef int int32_t'
 typedef int   int32_t;
               ^~~~~~~
```

Considering how basic `zero_out.cc` seems (at least to my novice eyes), my suspicion is that the main problem lies elsewhere. Notably, my attempts to build existing ops also triggered conflicting declaration errors, so even if I've made some mistake in writing `zero_out.cc`, that's not the full extent of the problem. From what I've read, later C++ standards supposedly fixed issues related to variable templates, but I've gotten the same exact errors regardless of whether I use `-std=c++11`, `-std=c++14`, or `-std=c++17` as options in the call to `g++` (among other options that I've attempted). It also doesn't seem like one should have to manually rewrite a bunch of standard installed files just to build a basic op... I hope.

There's probably some laughably simple mistake that is escaping my grasp, so I apologize for what is likely a very basic question from a novice. Nonetheless, any insights that you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

(Just in case it's relevant, I initially tried building tensorflow from source and encountered numerous problems with bazel and bazelisk. More recently, after having uninstalled my previous tensorflow version, I installed tensorflow from `pip`, which worked, as least as far as I can tell. However, I'm not sure if any artifacts left behind by my earlier installation attempts might be conflicting with the new installation, and to be frank, I'm unfamiliar enough with tensorflow that I'm not even sure how to begin diagnosing such an issue.)

**UPDATE:** I wound up biting the bullet and just using Visual Studio for kernel compilation--even though I wanted to avoid needlessly relying on a proprietary tool, there didn't seem to be much of a choice. In case it helps others, the below command prompt worked for `zero_out.cc`:

```
cpp -std=c++11 -msse2 -shared "C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/zero_out.cc" -o "C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/zero_out.so" -I "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include" -l tensorflow_framework -L "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow"
```

With that said, I'd still be interested in any potential solutions involving `g++` or a comparable tool, so I'll leave this question as-is so that others can post any answers that they have. (Additionally, while the above line of code worked for `zero_out.cc`, it resulted in errors for some other kernels. That seems to be a distinct issue, though, so I'll post it as a separate question if I can't resolve it on my own.)